# Connect from one Docker container to another with host ip

Tags: networking, docker

I'm having 2 VM machine and on each VM there are 2 docker containers, connect with bridge, I need to have a connection betwwen 2 containers on the same VM with the host ip.

One container is postgres. when I'm trying to send him a query from the other VM (psql -d -h ...) its works fine. but when running the same query with the container inside the same VM im getting an error: psql: could not connect to server: No route to host.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Take a look at this post (http://superuser.com/questions/1141553), it may help.

Comment: it doesn't help me.